# Sqlcmd from app service to local SQL Server using hybrid connection

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have setup an Azure app service with a hybrid connection to my local on premise SQL Server 2014.

The connection is just fine I can ping it from app service using tcpping.

However I cannot make the connection to the database. The `sqlcmd` command fails complaining about the user / pass - but they are correct.

I am using this command

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -d Sample_Dev -U xxx -P xxxx -I
```

I am getting this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user 'xxx'

I have searched online for that error and I am unable to make it work. Can you please help me on that ? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: The SQL Server log will have more information about the login failure.  The message sent to the client is intentionally vague.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by creating a database user directly on mssql and not using AD.